# Regex for Bash script to filter MIPS instruction

Tags: bash, mips

I have been trying to devise an expression that checks against MIPS instructions such as this on:

```
lw $t1 70000($s0)
```

I have expressions for the `lw` and the `$t1` part, but I am stuck on the `70000($s0)` part.

The number before the `($s0)` cannot exceed `−32768` or `32767`, the `$` has to be there only once, the `s` part has to be an `s` or a `t` and only occur once and the number afterwards can only range from `0-7` for `s` and `0-9` for `t`.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Here is the expression I have for the `$s0` part from another section of my script:

```
^(\$((s?[0-7])|(t?([0-9]))))$
```

I am using this in an if statement to check if the inputted text is valid, it is mainly the prefixed number part I am stuck on.

Thanks

**EDIT1:** I have managed to separate the value from the `($s0)` using `offset=${w3%(*}` to truncate the string to before the first `(`. My script wont deal with anything such as a `(` before the value.

I now need to check whether this value is less than `−32768` or greater than `32767`. Any idea as to how I can archive this?

**EDIT2:** I have managed to solve my problem and posted the solution as an answer, thanks to all that responded.

Comment: Is there any reason the range check needs to be within the regular expression? It would be easier to use a simple general expression for the number, then check the specific value later by referring to the capture group.

Comment: I guess it would be easier but I'm new to bash and regex isn't one of my strong points so I'm not sure how would I check the number part separately. Could you provide an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have managed to solve this, here is how:

```
    offset1=${w3%(*}                                                    # retrive the offset of the instruction

        if [[ ${offset1:0:1} == "-" ]]; then                                            # if the first char is a - then,
            offset1NoSign=${w3%(*}                                              # get the offset number
            offset1NoSign=${offset1NoSign##*-}                                      # get rid of the -
            echo " This should not have a - sign: $offset1NoSign"
        fi

        if [[ ( ${offset1:0:1} == "-" && $offset1NoSign -gt "32768" ) || ( $offset1 -gt "32767" ) ]]; then  
            echo "Out of bounds immediate. Immediates range between −32768 and 32767."

        else

---- rest of code ----
```

Its not very pretty but it works. It firsts truncates the string using `offset1=${w3%(*}` to get the number before the `(` (for example. `-500($s0)` would be truncated to `-55`).

Then it checks if the first character is a `-` if so remove it:

```
if [[ ${offset1:0:1} == "-" ]]; then                                            # if the first char is a - then,
            offset1NoSign=${w3%(*}                                              # get the offset number
            offset1NoSign=${offset1NoSign##*-}                                      # get rid of the -
            #echo " This should not have a - sign: $offset1NoSign"
        fi
```

Next, check if it exceeds the two numbers

```
if [[ ( ${offset1:0:1} == "-" && $offset1NoSign -gt "32768" ) || ( $offset1 -gt "32767" ) ]]; then  
            echo "Out of bounds immediate. Immediate range between −32768 and 32767."

        else
```

It check if the first character is a `-` and if it is greater than `32768` or if the number is just greater than `32767`.

The rest of the instruction just uses regular expressions to check it.

Answer (score 1):

`(-?[0-9]{1,5})\(\$(s[0-7]|t[0-9])\)`
I agree that it's wasted effort to have a regex detect a numeric range. The above captures the offset and register as you described them, with a bit of correction and simplification.

Comment: Could you provide some comments or explanations to your answer?